# Returning the Default Property

Tags: vba, excel

I fill **A1** and **A2** as follows:

[image]

I then run:

```
Sub WhatIsGoingOn()
    Dim r As Range, sh As Worksheet

    Set r = Range(Cells(1, 1))
    Set sh = Sheets(Cells(2, 1))
End Sub
```

I expected that in both cases, *VBA* would use the default property of Cells (the *Value*) property to Set each variable.  However I get a runtime error 13 on the last line of code!

In order to avoid errors, I must use:

```
Sub WhatIsGoingOn2()
    Dim r As Range, sh As Worksheet

    Set r = Range(Cells(1, 1))
    Set sh = Sheets(Cells(2, 1).Value)
End Sub
```

What is going on here ??

Comment: Interesting question,  You can also wrap it in CStr() and it will work without the value. `Sheets(CStr(Cells(1, 2)))`.  So it must be something to do with Sheets() itself.

Comment: It appears that Sheets() is not bringing in the value as a string but trying to bring the value in as a Long.  If you put `1` in A2 It will grab the first sheet in the index without the `.Value`.  So to bring in the name it is requiring that it be told it is a string, with CStr, .Value or you could `"" & Cells(2, 1)`  I think that it is because the default lookup for Sheets() is the index as a Long and not a string.

Comment: @ScottCraner  I think you have found something...............I will experiment some more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in how the input to their default properties is handled by the implementation of the `Range` and `Sheets` objects.

The default property of both the `Range` and the `Sheets` object takes a parameter of type `Variant`. You can pass anything to it, so no type coercion will be necessary. In your first example you pass a Range object to both.

How the default properties handle the input is up to themselves. Apparently the property of the `Range` tries to retrieve the default value of the passed parameter, in your example an address as String. The `Sheets` object doesn't seem to be so forgiving and raises an error because you neither passed a number nor a String.

Inconsistency is one of the strengths of VBA...

Btw., passing `CStr(Cells(2, 1))` would also work, because you explicitly cast to String before passing as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps Leviathan's comment that "Inconsistency is one of the strengths of VBA..." may ring true, but there are some contextual details that his answer neglects (and is technically incorrect on some subtle points).  He is correct that for the given code that all of the parameters are variants, but the statement that "no type coercion will be necessary" can be misleading and perhaps just wrong in many cases.  Even if many objects and methods are programmed to handle multiple types and default values, this very question reveals that it is a mistake to avoid purposely ensuring (or coercing) the correct data type.  Avoiding default properties altogether (by always typing out the full reference) can avoid many headaches.

A significant difference between the lines of code *for this particular question* is this:  ***Range* is a *property* that takes parameters, while *Sheets* is also a property but has *no* parameters.  *Range* and *Sheets* are NOT objects in this context**, even though they are properties which *do* return Range and Sheets objects, respectively.  They are **properties** of an (automatic global) object defined for the particular module or Excel workbook instance.  This detail is not trivial for understanding what the code is actually doing.

The Obect Browser in the VBA window reveals the following metadata for the two properties:

```
Property Range(Cell1, [Cell2]) As Range
Property Sheets As Sheets
```

For `Range(Cells(1, 1))`, the argument `Cells(1,1)` is passed to the parameter `Cell1`.  `Cells` itself is a property of the `Excel.Global` hidden object and it returns a Range object, so that `Cells(rowindex, colindex)` is calling a hidden default property of the Range class equivalent to `Cells._Default(rowindex, colindex)`.  The return type of the property `_Default()` is not declared, so technically it could return any type in a variant, but inspection shows that it returns a Range object.  Apparently passing a Range object to its default property will attempt to take the default value and if it is a valid range value, like a string with a range expression, then it will execute without error.

The default property for the Sheets class is the parameterized hidden `_Default(Index)` method.  Thus, `Sheets(Cells(2, 1))` is equivalent to `Sheets._Default(Cells(2, 1))`.  More importantly, it means that `Sheets._Default(Cells(2, 1))` is passing a Range object as an index value, but documentation says that it expects an integer or string value.  We already mentioned that the `index` parameter is variant... and when passing an object to a variant, it always passes the actual object and never its default property.  So we know that `Sheets.Item` obtains a Range object in that call.  Here is were Levithan was correct in that Sheets.Item can decide what to do with it.  It is likely that it could have been smart enough to get the single string value and continue without error.  Other collection objects (with a default Item(index) property) in MS Office objects do not seem to exhibit this same "pickiness", so it appears that `Sheets._Default()` (and perhaps `Sheets.Item()`) is being rather strict on validating its arguments.  But this is just a particular design issue with this method only... not necessarily an overall issue with VBA.

---

What can be difficult is determining exactly what the source objects of the properties are.  Inside the ThisWorkbook module, `Me.Sheets` reveals that Sheets is a property of the particular Workbook for the module.  But `Me.Range` is not valid in the Workbook module, but right-clicking on the `Range` property (without the Me qualifier) and choosing "Definition" results in the message "Cannot jump to Range because it is hidden".  However, once in the Object Browser, righ-clicking within the browser one can choose "Show Hidden Members" which will then allow navigating to the hidden Global objects and other hidden members.

Why the inconsistency and the hidden properties? In an attempt to make the current instance of Excel and all of its components accessible in a "natural" way, Excel (and all Office applications) implement these various hidden properties to avoid the "complexity" of having to repeatedly discover and type out full references.  For instance, the automatic global Application object also has both Range and Sheets properties.  Actual [documentation for Application.Sheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822920(v=office.15).aspx), for example, says "Using this property without an object qualifier is equivalent to using ActiveWorkbook.Sheets".  Even that documentation fails to say is that ActiveWorkbook is in turn a property of the global Excel Application object'.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @CPerkins I like your answer better.  IMHO the accepted answer has too many equivocations (apparantley, seems to, ...) BTW I'll delete my coments now as they are not relavent to the A in it's current form